# What does "the save DC is Charisma-based." mean?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm looking at Ghoul Fever and it says that, but a few lines up it says the save is Fort DC 13, so I'm not sure what they mean by the charisma based part.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The note is telling you that the Save DC of the disease is based, in part, on the Ghoul's Charisma modifier. This is only important if the Ghoul is (de-)buffed in some way, or if you are creating a modified version of the Ghoul with different stats. It is not normally relevant information.

Comment: +1 for emphasizing that the information is only relevant if you have a ghoul with a different Charisma score than usual (though remember debuffs are equally possible).